# WSO2 Stream Processor oauth2 authorization

Tags: wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am currently using stream processor and was exploring to use oauth2 authorization while creating siddhi apps
Basically, WSO2 Identity Server can act a Identity provider for authorization for stream processor.
Is there any provision present currently in 4.3.0 SP version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use External IDP client https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/User+Management+via+the+IdP+Client+Interface#UserManagementviatheIdPClientInterface-ExternalIdPClient

Comment: Thanks again.
I am going through the link, but can you please also highlight if this case is possible where individual users can create their own siddhi apps using oauth token. 
also, in that case ldap or database sharing is not required?

Comment: Yes users can invoke siddhi management API to deploy siddhi apps in that case "Authorization: Bearer <Valid OAuth token>" will work

Comment: thanks. I got it working but somehow I am getting this error for one of the user
Insufficient permissions to list Siddhi Apps

Comment: Roles are but you have to assign managing siddhi app permissions to those roles,

Comment: You can use https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Permission+APIs#PermissionAPIs-Addapermissionstring here, appName will be SAPP and permission string will be siddhiApp.manage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201270/discussion-between-2437850-and-niveathika).

Comment: Even after adding App and permission, its throws same error..